# Docker not expose ports for node and webpack dev-server

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, server, port

I have MacOS High Sierra and my goal is to run node web-applications without installation node on macos (I wanna use docker to do it). That web-application is usually angular-webpack (compilation + run dev serwer).

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /work
CMD while true; do sleep 10000; done
EXPOSE 3002
```

The line `CMD while ...` makes that container will be not killed by docker after run it - this allow us to "login" into container (by `docker exec -it...`).

Bash script **run.cmd** which run container:

```
set -e
docker build -t node-cmd .
docker rm -f node-cmd |:
docker run -d --name node-cmd -p 3002:3002 -v /Volumes/work:/work node-cmd
docker exec -it node-cmd /bin/bash
```

Where `/Volumes/work` is directory on my MacOs which contains angular projects.

Here is example application in file **/work/tmp/example.js** (mapped in container) for which problem is visible (however them main goal is to find proper configuration of webpack dev-server):

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n'+new Date);
}).listen(3002, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3002/');
```

So first I run `run.cmd` - here is what `docker ps` write:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e22188d8e136        node-cmd            "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"R…"   16 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp   node-cmd
```

Inside container I type commands:

```
root@5cd3773e7815:/work# cd tmp
root@5cd3773e7815:/work# node example.js & 
[1] 18
root@5cd3773e7815:/work/tmp# Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3002/
```

So serwer was start. Now I test:

```
root@5cd3773e7815:/work/tmp# curl 127.0.0.1:3002
Hello World
```

So inside docker everything works fine. Now when I go to my macos Chrome browser `http://127.0.0.1:3002` i get

> This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

If I remove `-p 3002:3002` from **run.cmd** file the browser response change to

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I also try tu use `docker run --ip=127.0.0.1...` but I get message that

> docker: Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is
>   supported on user defined networks only.

When i try to use `docker run --net=host ...` it doesn't change anything

I alswo wanna mention that when I run `mysql` image by `docker run -p 3306:3306 ...` I works properly (!) - so may be the problem is with `node` image (?)

Questions:

1. How to "unblock" port 3002 in container to allow host browser to connect with service inside container?
2. How to use subdomains like `subdomain.local:3002` too?
3. How to use subdomains using **webpack devServer** (used in angular) instead above `example.js` (i need to have run many angular web-application each on different port with individual subdomain) ?

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Comment: `docker -v` Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825

Comment: Can you use the IP address of the container, instead of 127.0.0.1, when testing from the host?

Comment: When I run `docker inspect node-cmd | grep "IPAddress"` to get this address i get: "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
(my docker installation is fresh - i do it 2 days ago and don't change anything excep download images by `docker pull`)

Comment: Then https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2670#issuecomment-371249949 could help.

Comment: Looks like port is working, try `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3002` 

it's something with node js and host resolving, try to add virtual host with different name (not 127.0.0.1 or localhost)

Comment: For subdomain, just add `subdomain.local` to your hosts file

Comment: @bxN5 after try `netstst` I get:
tcp6       0      0  ::1.3002               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   3830      0
tcp4       0      0  *.3002                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   3830      0

what next?

Comment: @VonC I read (including "deep" links) but I don't see the answer there

Comment: Agreed, that would not address the sub-domain part of your question anyway.

Comment: @VonC Now the problem 2 left - subdomains - when I use `nginx:latest` I only set subdomain in `/etc/hosts` and configure nginx and everything works (no need to extra docker configuration). So may be I need to proper configre node serwer?

Comment: @VonC I update question and find answer

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Great! Don't forget you can post (and accept) your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this issue might be related to the fact that you are specifying `127.0.0.1` as host. Try to use `0.0.0.0` instead:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n'+new Date);
}).listen(3002, '0.0.0.0');
```

For subdomains you will most likely have to edit the `/etc/hosts` file on your local machine.

Comment: I try your solution - works (even If i type `http://localhost:3002` it works), however what about second part of the question - subdomains (this is very important for me because I need to run many servers at the same time (on different subdomain:port) - ?

Comment: I will give plus 1

Comment: Is it necessary that all the sites are accessed via the same port (`3002`)? Otherwise you could just use a different port mapping like `-p 3003:3002` etc.

Comment: In my case I wanna use different port for each site - but, the critical point is to have different subdomain for each site (angular) because my backend (php) responses are request subdomain dependent... (each my Client have separate frontend with different subdomain and my backend recognize them by subdomain)

Comment: I update question and find answer - thanks for help :)

Comment: I read your answer again and see that you give answer infact (`etc/hosts`) so I will accept it - however I update question and add point 3 for webpack

Answer (score 3):

[Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4430246/rob) Helps me to find main part solution of problem. I make tests and investigation and find out that when we set `.listen(3002, '0.0.0.0')` and edit `/etc/hosts` by add line like

```
127.0.0.1 node-test.local
```

And when we type in browser `node-test.local:3002` it will works. However if we use webpack dev starter, in browser we get error:

> Invalid Host header

So we need reconfugre webpack.js file (e.g. in [angular-starter framework](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter) (**ASF**) it is in `./config/webpack.dev.js`) by adding `disableHostCheck: true` - here is egzample of configuration:

```
devServer: {
  port: "3002",            // in ASF is METADATA.port,
  host: "0.0.0.0",         // in ASF is METADATA.host,     
  public: "0.0.0.0:3002",  // in ASF is METADATA.public,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  //...
}
```

After that `http://node-test.local:3002` should works on MacOs Browsers.

If we need to have many subdomains on one port number (which is out of frame of this question) then probably we must use [reverse-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) (which is probably standard solution for docker multi-webapps(subdomains) over port 80)